# MacOS Monterey does not display icons in menubar

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

This is a weird issue.I am on a Mac Pro (Late 2013).This Mac was recently purchased via marketplace. Everything is functioning except for the missing icons on the menubar.

[image]

Although all icons are ticked for 'Show in Menu Bar', only icons visible in normal mode are spotlight,siri and Time Machine.

Icons such as Wifi,Bluetooth,ControlCentre,Sound dont appear on the menubar.The Wifi & bluetooth modules work correctly when connected via System Preferences.
**The 'Show in Menu Bar' option is ticked for every item within System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar.**

I have tried the following with no luck:

- Removing Cache folder
- Restarting SystemUI with Kill all command
- updating to the latest macos 12.6.4 through 'About This Mac'
- removed any login items from the admin user account
- created a new admin user
- reinstalling the software via system recovery

When I boot into safe mode the missing icons appears but on restart to normal mode they disappear again.Any ideas how I can get these icons to show up?

Comment: If Safe Boot fixes it, but a new user account doesn't, then the problem is something installed in /Library (the root level Library, not user Library). Most likely a Launch Agent or Launch Daemon. Everything looks very blue -- is that related?

Comment: Can you get a clearer picture of the top right of the screen - this looks very odd; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK43Q.png Menu bar items floating in free space, with a squashed & blurred menu bar above it. If you haven't done yet, nuke & pave the machine. Start absolutely fresh, nothing left over from any previous user. Basically Step 8 onwards from this - [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)

Comment: @Tetsujin here is  a clearer image https://imgur.com/a/WW2po4F . There is a faint seperation between the menubar and the main desktop.The wallpaper is the default one for Monterey

Comment: @benwiggy I think blue is just the default Monterey OS wallpaper.  How do I reset the Launch Agent/Daemon?

Comment: The Monterey default wallpaper is purple stylized mountain valleys (Overlapping Vs). I'd recommend downloading EtreCheck, which will give you a nice report of the 'state' of your OS, and things you've installed. You can then delete anything that you don't need. https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html